# Java Matcher and Pattern: Why does this go on forever

Tags: java, regex

```
//remove multiple with
       pat=Pattern.compile("ACCEPT .*?\\.",Pattern.DOTALL);
       m=pat.matcher(str);       
       while(m.find())
       {

          int start=m.group().indexOf("WITH") +1;
          String part=m.group().substring(start);
          part=part.replaceAll("WITH", "");
          part=m.group().substring(0, start).concat(part);

          if(!m.group().equals(part))
          {

              str=m.replaceFirst(part);

          }

       }
```

Any idea why this is an infinite loop? `m.group` is never equal to `part`.  I don't know why. Tried reset but nothing.

Comment: It varies.. It starts with ACCEPT and ends with . dot..

Comment: Perhaps you should add a test string and what you'd like your code to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish, but there is a bug here:

```
if(!m.group().equals(part))
{
    str=m.replaceFirst(part);
}
```

You are reassigning `str`, while the matcher still works on the original value of `str`. Strings are immutable, if you reassign the variable in one place, it doesn't change the reference in another (see **Passing Reference Data Type Arguments** on [this page of the Sun java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)).

There are some more strange things going on, but perhaps I'm not understanding you correctly.
You say in a comment that the string **starts with ACCEPT and ends with . dot**. But that is the only thing you are searching for `Pattern.compile("ACCEPT .*?\\.",Pattern.DOTALL);`, and you are not capturing anything either. Then why bother searching in the first place? I thought you knew that the input Strings are like that.

What you should really do is post some sample input and what data you want to extract from it. Otherwise no one will be able to really help you.

---

I am guessing now: you seem to want to remove multiple WITH clauses from your String. This should be much easier, something like this:

```
String test =
    "ACCEPT pasta "
       + "WITH tomatoes, parmesan cheese, olives "
       + "WITH anchovies WITH tuna WITH more olives.";

System.out.println(
    test.replaceAll(
        "(ACCEPT.*?WITH.*?)(?:\\s*WITH.*)(\\.)", "$1$2"
    )
);
```

**Output:**

> ACCEPT pasta WITH tomatoes, parmesan
>   cheese, olives.

Here's the Pattern, explained:

```
(       // start a capturing group
ACCEPT  // search for the literal ACCEPT
.*?     // search for the shortest possible matching String
        // (so no other WITH can sneak in)
WITH    // search for the literal WITH
.*?     // search for the shortest possible matching String
        // (so no other WITH can sneak in)
)       // close the capturing group, we'll refer to this
        // group as $1 or matcher.group(1)
(?:     // start a non-capturing group
\\s*    // search for optional whitespace
WITH    // search for the literal WITH
.*      // search for anything, greedily
)       // close the group, we'll discard this one
(       // open another capturing group
\\.     // search for a single period
)       // close the group, the period is now accessible as $2
```

---

Given your updated requirements (remove the WITHs but keep the args) here's an updated solution:

```
final Matcher matcher =
    Pattern.compile("WITH\\s*", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(test);
final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()){
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, sb.length() == 0
        ? matcher.group()
        : "");
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**Output:**

> ACCEPT pasta WITH tomatoes, parmesan cheese, olives anchovies tuna more olives.

Comment: You guessed almost right.. It is a  tool i made to migate the old COBOL code for the new compiler. Your work arround does not work as i want...  I want to remove the extra WITH words ,in other words after olives it should print anchovies tina more olives

Comment: While Tina might go down nicely with pasta, I'm guessing you mean Tuna :-) I'll add an update in a sec.